# Book analysis on metric spaces and geodesics.

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, geodesic, absolute-continuity

I am looking for a book that defines and proves results about absolutely continuous curves in metric (i.e. curves of the form $\omega :[a,b]\to X$ where $X$ is a metric space) spaces and geodesic in metric spaces, in particular, things like

> The following facts are equivalent
>
> 1. $\omega$ is a constant-speed geodesic,
> 2. $\omega\in\operatorname{AC}(X)$ and $|\omega'|(t)=d(\omega(0),\omega(1))$ a.e
> 3. $\omega$ solves $\min\{\int_0^1|\omega'|(t)^pdt:\omega(0)=x_0,\omega(1)=x_1\}$

Is there any good reference?

Comment: Derivatives and integrals are not generally defined on metric spaces, so it's not clear what you actually want to know.

Comment: The derivative is not but the modulus $|\omega'|$ is right?

Comment: No, it is not. The closest thing I can think of is that [rectifiable curves and their path lengths](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rectifiable_curve) are defined in arbitrary metric spaces.

Comment: Can't we define $|\omega'|(t):=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{d(\omega(t+\epsilon),\omega(t))}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: Only if the limit exists.

Comment: [This](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:609061/FULLTEXT01.pdf) might be of interest

Comment: @SolubleFish, thank you!